# Simulating :focus on elements that don't support it, via Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, class, events, parent

I'm coming from a jQuery background and am trying to achieve some effects with Angular that were extremely easy with jQuery. I've tried getting Angular and jQuery to play nicely together, but that's more a headache than it's worth.

Essentially, what I would do in jQuery is create a virtual binding that worked on everything in the document, like so:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function() {
  $('.focus').removeClass('focus');
  $(this).addClass('focus');
  $(this).parents('*').addClass('focus');
});
```

This clears the `focus` class from anything that already has it, then sets it on the clicked element and all of its parent elements, bubbling all the way up to the root node of the document. From there I could selectively choose what to style as if it had `:focus`.

Is there a similar way to achieve the same effect in Angular? I'm am still relatively new to the framework, so if there is some sort of Angular specific terminology, please spell that bit out for me.

Comment: Just create a directive.

Comment: Not sure a directive is the way to go here. It seems to be more useful for descendant elements instead of parent elements. If I'm wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to manipulate with DOM, you always need to consider custom directive. In your case you could write a directive that would listen bubbled click events on the element it's applied to and in this case set `focus` class to the `event.target` element.

Naive implementation could be something like this:

```
app.directive('focusable', function() {
    return function(scope, element) {

        var focused = element[0].getElementsByClassName('focus');

        element.on('click', function(e) {

            if (e.target !== this) {
                angular.element(this).removeClass('focus');
            }

            while (focused.length) {
                angular.element(focused[0]).removeClass('focus');
            }

            angular.element(e.target).addClass('focus');
        });
    };
});
```

And here is a demo I was experimenting with:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aSupMEKsWsSYtNT2bfXp?p=info

Couple of notes. I used [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) in order to obtain live HTMLCollection, which is very helpful because I don't need to rescan entire DOM after new classes added, as `focused` collection being live - updates automatically.

Comment: That's pretty close, but can a directive set a focus class on every element all the way up the parent chain?

Comment: It's also possible. Check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/LqEpxx8aALrDwRK8qP5p?p=preview